# Java Swing: Error when dynamically adding JScrollpane to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

Update: If I move the code to be within the mouseclick event (i.e. instead of calling initMarksScreen() I just put the code directly in) it works as expected. So my problem is calling the code in its own method. Does this mean if I want to perform the same steps at another point or on a different button that I have to have the code directly in there instead of in a method I can call?

---

I am fairly new to Java and trying to create a button that adds a JScrollPane which contains a JTable.

It is called by:

```
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            initMarksScreen();
        }
```

The code is:

```
public final void initMarksScreen() {
    String[] columnNames = {"Student ID",
                            "Last Name",
                            "Firstname",
                            "Status",
                            "Degree",
                            "Candidate No.",
                            "Stage",
                            "Year",
                            "Code",
                            "Title",
                            "Grade Mode",
                            "Mark",
                            "Result"};
    Object[][] data = {
            {"100123456", "Cooper","Sheldon", "Signed Up", "BSc Physics","1201234","1","12","PH1001","Blackholes and Revelations","D",new Integer(99),"P"},
            {"100123456", "Cooper","Sheldon", "Signed Up", "BSc Physics","1201234","1","12","PH1025","Astrophysics","D",new Integer(95),"P"}
        };
    JTable tMarks = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tMarks);
    tMarks.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    panelCentral.add(scrollPane); --!!ERROR AT THIS LINE!!
    panelCentral.revalidate();
}
```

The panel is declared as:

```
private static final Container panelCentral = null;
```

As I'm quite new to Java I imagine there is an easy fix but if I need to add an SSCCE.

Everything displays fine until I click the button then the error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GUI.mainScreen.initMarksScreen(mainScreen.java:312)
at GUI.mainScreen$2.mouseClicked(mainScreen.java:183)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Guess panelCentral is null. Check the line 312. The panel must be created before adding the scroll.

Comment: When this code is called the panel has been created and shows up fine. Is this the same thing? Or does it literally have to be created and compile time?

Comment: *"but if I need to add an SSCCE."*  You need to add an SSCCE.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm new to posting, do I just copy and paste the code or can I attach a text file to the question somehow?

Comment: I've just put an update at the top of the question. Thanks all.

Comment: @joelpeddie, I don't think it is the problem of where you put the code. The problem is panelCentral is not initialized. You may have put the declaration of panelCentral or initMarkScreen() in a wrong place (maybe inside the inner class, and your initMarkScreen() method is in the outer class). I can't tell you more unless you show more code.

Answer (score 2):

if `panelCentral` is JPanel and its not initialized, initialize before add

```
 panelCentral = new JPanel();
 panelCentral.add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: Hi, panelCentral is created and displayed when the program runs (before this code is clicked). Thanks.